# Separate a paragraph list and give each word individual CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a paragraph with user generated content. The paragraph is a list with words that are separated by comma. So for example "dog, cat, hamster, turtle". I would like this list to be separated so that each word can be assigned its own attributes.

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXR7b.png)

As i the example above, instead of the list having a shared border and color. I want them to have their own "non-connected" border with spacing between them. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible (as your image demonstrates).  Wrap them in a `span` with a `class` you use to style it.  After trying, if you get stuck, post as a well-written question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it (though next time try to make some progress on your own) :

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bdvu1sdg/)

if this is your html:

```
<p id="example">dog, cat, hamster, turtle</p>
```

your js:

```
function seperateList() {
    var el =  document.getElementById("example");
    var array = el.innerHTML.split(",");
    
    el.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i =0; i<array.length;i++) {
        var _newa = document.createElement("span");
        var _a = array[i].trim();
            _newa.innerHTML= _a;
            el.appendChild(_newa);
    }
}

seperateList();
```

css:

```
#example span { padding:2px 5px; background:#e3e3e3; margin:0 5px; border-radius:6px;}
```

- Note that you could of course pass the element into the function as a parameter..
  if you have any questions feel free.. good luck!

Comment: @dfsq nice man :) the next step would be to pass in a group of elements at once.. say all the P tags under a certain container div.

Comment: @webkit I implemented the code directly to my site and for some reason the <span> elements still wants to share the background color with each other. They have no white spacing between them and they now share the same border-radius. [The result](http://i.imgur.com/1O8Erat.png) . The spans are not affected by any other css.

Comment: @HenrikSandstrom do you have a link to the code? or paste the generated HTML, what it seems like is that everything gets into the same SPAN.. are you sure the text is seperated by commas?

Comment: @webkit They all get into different spans. But I just noticed that there are no spacing in the original list "dog,cat,hamster". Is that the cause?

Comment: and here is the generated html
<p id="theservertags""><span><span>Survival mode</span><span>Creative mode</span><span>Hardcore mode</span><span>Spigot</span></span></p>

Comment: Ok, can you also post the html <p id="theservertags">... before the manipulation?

Comment: @webkit <p id="theservertags">Survival mode,Creative mode,Hardcore mode,Spigot</p>

Comment: @HenrikSandstrom hi, go here > http://jsfiddle.net/bdvu1sdg/2/ ::: can you reproduce the problem in the fiddle, if you can update it and send a link.

Comment: @webkit I solved it. Apparently when I called for the user created tags it created another span outside all the spans generated by your code. Solved it by removing that extra span. 
Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Henrik you can add special css to an specific word, use the span tag like:

```
<span class="red">Color Red</span>
```

then on you css

```
.red{color: red;}
```

and if you want the border just add another class like 
`.border-red{border: 1px red solid;}`

if the content is dinamically created it would be more complex but actually possible,
i hope this works!

Answer (score -1):

yes seperate all the word using Indexof and provide individual css